# Magento 2 : Category name filter in product grid in custom module

Tags: magento2, grid

I want to filter by category name in this product grid. How to do that?

[image]

My prepare collection code :

```
/**
     * [prepareCollection for grid]
     * @return collection
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection() {
        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $collection = $this->productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(
            'sku'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'name'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'attribute_set_id'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'type_id'
        )->setStore(
            $store
        );

        if ($this->moduleManager->isEnabled('Magento_CatalogInventory')) {
            $collection->joinField(
                'qty',
                'cataloginventory_stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left'
            );
        }
        if ($store->getId()) {
            $collection->setStoreId($store->getId());
            $collection->addStoreFilter($store);
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'name',
                'catalog_product/name',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'status',
                'catalog_product/status',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'visibility',
                'catalog_product/visibility',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute('price', 'catalog_product/price', 'entity_id', null, 'left', $store->getId());
        } else {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
            $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
            $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
        }

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks.