# Magento 2 : Join category name in product collection

Tags: magento2, product, grid

I want to join category name in product collection. I want to use that in product grid filter which is used in my custom module.

This is my collection code. It's same as like this **_prepareCollection()** :

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Grid.php

```
protected $productFactory;

public function __construct(
    .....
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    .....
) {
    .....
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    .....
}

protected function _prepareCollection() {
        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $collection = $this->productFactory->create()->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(
                'sku'
            )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'name'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'attribute_set_id'
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            'type_id'
        )->setStore(
            $store
        );
}
```

**EDIT :**

```
$collection->getSelect()->join(
            'catalog_category_product',
            'e.entity_id = catalog_category_product.product_id'
        )->join(
            'catalog_category_entity_varchar',
            'catalog_category_entity_varchar.entity_id = catalog_category_product.category_id AND catalog_category_entity_varchar.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = \'name\' and entity_type_id = 3)',
            ['categories' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`catalog_category_entity_varchar`.value SEPARATOR ",")')])
            ->group('sku');
```

How to do it?

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want as result since a product can be in more than one category. Therefore your grid would have more entries for one product sku if the product is in more than one category. Is that what you expect?

Comment: Yes. I display all category names.

Comment: See here, You get idea what i want. https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/265460/17154 Can you please help me? It will be too much helpful for me :)

Comment: Hey @HelgeB , Any idea? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to join some tables and use group concat to achieve that. For example thsi SQL statement gives you the sku of a product and the categories to which a product is assigned:

```
select main_table.sku, group_concat(catalog_category_entity_varchar.value) from catalog_product_entity main_table
join catalog_category_product on catalog_category_product.product_id = main_table.entity_id
join catalog_category_entity_varchar on catalog_category_entity_varchar.entity_id = catalog_category_product.category_id and catalog_category_entity_varchar.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'name' and entity_type_id = 3)
group by main_table.sku;
```

Translated into a Magento collection way it can like this (it can be done nicer of course, especially the varchar table join :-)):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$collection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory')->create();
$collection->getSelect()->join(
    'catalog_category_product',
    'e.entity_id=`catalog_category_product`.product_id')
->join(
    'catalog_category_entity_varchar',
    new \Zend_Db_Expr('`catalog_category_entity_varchar`.entity_id=`catalog_category_product`.category_id AND catalog_category_entity_varchar.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = \'name\' and entity_type_id = 3)'),
    array(
        'categories'  => new \Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`catalog_category_entity_varchar`.value SEPARATOR ",")'),)
    )->group('sku');
$collection->load();

echo $collection->count() . "\n";

foreach($collection as $product){
    echo $product->getSku() . " -- " . $product->getCategories() . "\n";
}
```

So you need to "translate" that into your prepare collection.

Comment: Did you see this file ? vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Grid.php. Is it not possible to do something in that code instead of query? Your answer is tricky :D

Comment: The second part of the answer is using a collection that gives you sku and categories. Use that with your collection and adapt it. You will also need to add a column to the grid and so on. The answer shows you how to use the join for your situation and is not the complete code for your requirement... you have to do that by yourself :-)

Comment: Can you please tell me what is attribute_code = \'name\' ?

Comment: The attribute code for the category name. And you want the value of that attribute

Comment: I created this query. It returns *A Joined field with this alias is already declared.* I edit question. Wherer I do mistake?

Comment: Hey @HelgeB Can you pls help me here? https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/294983/51810 Please solve this question.